# Cordova LocalFilesystem returns unusable path in Windows8?

Tags: windows, cordova, filesystems, file-permissions

I'm at my wits end with Cordova 3.5.0 and new FileSystem api. In Windows8 it returns path to

```
 \AppData\Local\Packages\packagename\LocalState or TempState
```

depending on filesystem selector. Those directories are read-only and also otherwise they seem to be out of application scope, for writing at least. Apparently there is a common appdata folder, but I have no idea if that is usable through Cordova Filesystem api? (particularly I'm talking about this, [new HTML5 like api](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md).

Code I'm using is very simple:

```
window.requestFileSystem(window.LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
          ...
window.fileTransfer.download(
                   uri,
                   fileSystem.root.toURL()+"testfile.pdf"
                   ...
```

And this causes exception which says that the folder is unusable and in location not accessible by application (it's in Finnish, I don't even try to translate it).

Unfortunately I'm rather unfamiliar with Windows development, but this smells a little like a bug like situation in Cordova.

Have any of you encountered this? Is there any other way?

Comment: Apparently this isn't fault at Cordova, but there's something really fishy going on the Asus tablet I'm developing on. Investigating further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by cordova-file-transfer plugin. Apparently it dislikes "/"-based path handling, but expects paths to be given in "\"-format as separator.